# Get array element value inside the current array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $array = {
    "firstVar" : 1,
    "secondVar" : this.firstVar + 1
};

console.log($array.firstVar); //1
console.log($array.secondVar); //NaN
```

How can i get access to array value from the another value of the same array?

Comment: array...object...no sense

Comment: Its an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)